# how to convert asynchronous promise code to rxjava

Tags: java, android, promise, rxjs, rx-java2

I have the following synchronous code that I would like to model as async code in RXJava.

```
void executeActions(List<Action> action) {
  if (action == null || action.size() == 0) return;
  for (Action action: actions) { 
     executeActions(action.handle());
  } 
}


class Action {

   //implementation of handle 
   // return List<Action> or null. 
   List<Action> handle() {
   } 
}
```

Now in JS I can model this interaction with Promises like so.  (Pseudo code below - my JS is weak)

```
executeActionsAsync(actions) { 
  var p = Promise.resolve(); 
  action.forEach(function(action) { 
    p = p.then(function() { 
           action.handle();    
        })
  } 
  return p; 
} 


class Action() { 
  function handle() { 
    actions = [];// some array of actions. 
    executeAsync(actions);
  } 
}
```

I would like to model the same in RXJava2. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, Sorry for my bad English.

**I edited entire answer because I did not catch what his question is.**

I don't know how implement of your Action class's handle function, However this function return value should change to RxJava2's async classes. In this case, Maybe class.

> 1. You wants how to implements recursion of async.
> 2. Handle List or null.

**Use Maybe if you want to handle something or null. in RxJava2**

```
class Action {
  Maybe<List<Action>> handle() {}
}
```

This is what your Action class's handle returns.

```
void executeActions(Maybe<List<Action>> rxactions) {
  // add null check.
  // List<Action> handles as stream, but you can use for or iterator or whatever you want.
  rxactions.subscribe(actions -> actions.stream().map(action -> executeActions(action.handle())));
}
```

Important thing is, handle() function returns properly.

> Additional

In RxJava2, There are multiple classes to handle async.
Single, Flowable, Observable, Completable. And each classes instance method, subscribe.

Simply say,

1.Single => returns single class.

2.Flowable, Observable => returns multiple classes. (Flowable is more complex than Observable, which added back pressure.)

3.Completable => returns nothing, just succeed or not.

4.Maybe is returns * or null.

5.subscribe is execute this async.

**:: Each classes can convert easily.**

**:: And There are so many ways to solve one problem. so it is just reference.**

```
ex) Single<List<Foo>> <=> Flowable<Foo> // This is not same. but treat as similar.
```

> PS.

I had this experience too. I think you need to learn more about RxJava2 to use properly everywhere.

**Promise can devide into Single, Flowable, Observable, Completable. As describe above. This is the KEY to start understanding RxJava2.**

Comment: i m not sure how this answering my question at all. If not clear the promises are chained both via then blocks as well as with recursion.

Comment: @rOrlig Oh, you mean your key of question is recursion of promises?????, It doesn't matter I think, however I'll edit with additional explanation.